# Application screenshot issue

Tags: iphone

My application has just been approved, but the problem is that when checking link on itunes it is showing 5 screen shot but when iam checking through my iphone its showing only 3 images. any one know why is this happening? ny other application are alright that is they are showing all 5 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your iPhone is an iPhone 4 (with retina display), and some of your screenshots are in the old, lower resolution, then annoyingly they won't be displayed in iTunes on that device.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation for this, but I've seen it happen to me.  Most recently I experienced a lag that resolved itself within about 24 hours.

If the screenshots don't appear by tomorrow I would remove and re-add them in iTunes Connect and that should fix the problem.

Comment: thats not possible .... if this has been the issue then none of my image should have been on display

Comment: in my situation, I saw two out of the five images on the iPhone, but all five appeared in iTunes.  I can't explain it, but it just proves it can happen, and that probably the images aren't served from the same location (thus the lag).  Now that I read Mike's answer, I wonder if my issue was the resolution of the screenshots.